# I need the format of CSV file for English to Hindi for Zend Tranlation

Tags: php, zend-framework, csv, translation, pootle

I have zend csv file for English Dictionary. Its format is :-

> ```
>  All Rights Reserved;All Rights Reserved
>    Homepage;Home
>    Help;Help
>    Contact Us;Contact Us
>    Refresh;Refresh;
>    Add;Add
>    Save;Save
>    Save Changes;Save Changes
>    Cancel;Cancel
> ```

I have translate this into **hindi** using **pootle**. I have export it into Csv again but the pootle csv format is different from Zend.

Format of csv export from pootle

> ```
>   Page Reports;Reports;रिपोर्ट
>   Page Charts;Graphs & Charts;रेखांकन और चार्ट
>   Page Eventlog;Event Log;इवेंट लॉग
>   Page Users/Groups;Users & Groups;उपयोगकर्ता और
> ```

But this csv is for accept format for zend. Please tell me what is the zend csv format for above

Comment: csv is csv, there's no zend csv or pootle csv. technically neither example is a csv as they don't use commas, aside from that, i'm not sure what the real question is.

Comment: No, The zend csv parser for tranalation has a fixed format. It will not take any format.

Comment: I am looking for the zend csv file for any lanuage so that i can create csv file for Hindi

Answer (score 0):

At Last, i have found the answer.

The pootle csv output format is:

```
Source;Target
Page Reports;Reports;रिपोर्ट
Page Charts;Graphs & Charts;रेखांकन और चार्ट
```

If we want to use that in zend translation, we have to edit the csv to this format:

```
Source;Target
Page Reports;रिपोर्ट
Page Charts;रेखांकन और चार्ट
```

i.e. drop the first column from Pootle output.  In this way, zend will accept the csv as input for translation.

Good Luck